# Using NSPredicate to refer other NSPredicate rules

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

Let's say I have a Core Data database for `NSPredicate` rules.

```
enum PredicateType,Int {
case beginswith
case endswith
case contains
}
```

My Database looks like below

```
+------+-----------+
| Type |  Content  |
+------+-----------+
|    0 | Hello     |
|    1 | end       |
|    2 | somevalue |
|    0 | end       |
+------+-----------+
```

I have a content "This is end". How can I query Core Data to check if there is any rule that satisfies this content? It should find second entry on the table

```
+------+-----------+
| Type |  Content  |
+------+-----------+
|    1 | end       |
+------+-----------+
```

but shouldn't find

```
+------+-----------+
| Type |  Content  |
+------+-----------+
|    0 | end       |
+------+-----------+
```

Because in this sentence `end` is not at the beginning.

Currently I am getting all values, Create predicate with Content and Type and query the database again which is a big overhead I believe.

Comment: Do you have only 3 types?

Comment: I have 3 types for now but I am planning to increase the types. I guess you want to suggest, checking all 3 types and check if there is a match? But this is also small table, I have other properties for the predicate as well lets say case insensitivity etc.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you have one or two databases and in which one is value and content? Which database do you want to query?

Comment: I have Database which contains `NSPredicate` Rules such as `BEGINSWITH, ENDSWITH, CONTAINS` I want to query database for all rules to find out if there is any `NSPredicate` rule that fits the content.

Comment: I would load the rules in memory, create (or store/load) a predicate for each rule and filter the rules using a block. Another idea (don't know if it will work): add a regular expression to the database and use a predicate like "'This is end' MATCHES contentRegex".

Answer (score 1):

They way you doing it now is correct.  You first need to build your predicate (which in your case is very complex operation that also requires fetching) and run each predicate to see if which one matches.

I wouldn't be so quick to assume that there is a huge overhead with this.  If your data set is small (<300) I would suspect that there would be no problem with this at all.  If you are experencing problems then (and only then!) you should start optimizing.

If you see the app is running too slowly then use instrements to see where the issue is.  There are two possible places that I could see having perforance issues - 1) the fetching of all the predicates from the database and 2) the running of all of the predicates.

If you want to make the fetching faster, then I would recommend using a `NSFetchedResultsController`.  While it is generally used to keep data in sync with a tableview it can be used for any data that you want to have a correct data for at any time.  With the controller you do a single fetch and then it monitors core-data and keeps itself up to data.  Then when you you need all of the predicate instead of doing a fetch, you simply access the contoller's `fetchedObjects` property.

If you find that running all the predicates are taking a long time, then you can improve the running for beginsWith and endsWith by a clever use of a bianary search.  You keep two arrays of custom predicate objects, one sorted alphabetically and the other will all the revered strings sorted alphabetically.  To find which string it begins with use `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` to find the relevant objects.  If don't know how you can improve contains.  You could see if running string methods on the objects is faster then NSPredicate methods.  You could also try running the predicates on a background thread concurrently.

Again, you shouldn't do any of this unless you find that you need to.  If your dataset is small, then the way you are doing it now is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I can't use `NSFetchedResultsController` for this because it is a utility method, content comes in result comes out. I was hoping to find an answer with some cool SQL trick or using `SUBQUERY` with `SELF` or something to refer itself.